# How to add json objects to POJO from Gson

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, pojo, gson

I want to add post.java between DataRetriver.java  code .Because i want to use pojo object and post.java has pojo object. I think I can add id = array_items.optInt("id"); but i know it.

DataRetriver.java

```
        for (int i = 0; i < names_count; i++) {
            JSONObject array_items = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            ListValues jsonValues, pictureValue;
            switch (type) {
                case 1:
                    id = array_items.optInt("id");
                    name = array_items.optString("name");
                    jsonValues = new ListValues(id, name);
                    listValues.add(jsonValues);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    id = array_items.optInt("userId");
                    name = array_items.optString("title");
                    if (id == recieved_id) {
                        jsonValues = new ListValues(id, name);
                        listValues.add(jsonValues);
                    }
                    break;
```

Post.java

```
public class Post implements Serializable {
@SerializedName("userId")
private int userId;
@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
public String name;

@SerializedName("id")
private int id;

@SerializedName("title")
private String title;

@SerializedName("body")
private String body;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(int userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}


public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getBody() {
    return body;
}

public void setBody(String body) {
    this.body = body;
}
```

}

Your advice important for me

Thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/4158/gson/15339/custom-json-deserializer-using-gson#t=201703070046152458861

Comment: It should pretty straight-forward to convert between Java POJOs and JSON strings using Google's Gson library! Have you considered that instead of doing everything manually?